# O que quer dizer isto "people[last, first]" em Python?

Tags: python-3.x, sintaxe

É a primeira vez que vejo esta sintaxe `people[last, first]` com a virgula a separar os indexes no Python. Eu nem sei que estrutura de dados é `people`.

A pergunta é

> What does this statement do:

```
for last, first in people:
    print(last, first, people[last, first])
```

> Be sure you understand the structure of the dictionary and its keys.

Desta ultimo conselho parece que people é o dicionário, mas acho que com um normal dicionário esta sintaxe não é permitida, pois este código:

```
 person = {"Name": "Barack", "Surname": "Obama"}

 for last, first in person:
   print(person[last, first])
```

dá-me erro:

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

People tem que ter 2 valores, pois esses são salvados em `last` e `first`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente, `people` é um dicionário que mapeia **tuplas** para outros dados:

```
>>> people = {("Obama", "Barack"):"USA", ("Roussef", "Dilma"):"BRA"}
>>> for last, first in people:
...   print(last, first, people[last, first])
...
Roussef Dilma BRA
Obama Barack USA
```

Caso não esteja familiarizado com tuplas, o tipo de dados `tuple` é como se fosse uma lista, só que imutável:

```
x = (10, 20, 30)
y = ()
z = (10,)   # Aqui a vírgula é obrigatória, pra não se confundir com 10 entre parênteses
```

O que torna as coisas confusas é que a sintaxe do Python aceita que você omita os parênteses caso a tupla tenha 2 ou mais elementos:

```
x = 10, 20, 30
```

Ou seja, `people[last, first]` é o mesmo que `people[(last, first)]`.

Quanto ao tipo de dados `people`, eu deduzi que fosse um `dict` pois é a única maneira desse código fazer sentido. Arrays (listas) somente permitem que se indexe por número, não por tuplas, então `people` não é um array. Já um `dict` permite tuplas como chaves, e como o `for` aplicado a um dicionário itera sobre suas chaves, imaginei que essa fosse a estrutura de dados certa.

A propósito, você pode iterar sobre listas/tuplas e seus índices ou dicionários e seus valores usando `enumerate` e `items`, respectivamente:

```
>>> lista = [10, 20, 30]
>>> for indice, valor in enumerate(lista):
...   print(indice, valor)
...
0 10
1 20
2 30
>>> person = {"Name": "Barack", "Surname": "Obama"}
>>> for chave, valor in person.items():
...   print(chave, valor)
...
Name Barack
Surname Obama
```

Esses exemplos funcionam porque tanto `enumerate` quanto `items` retornam tuplas. Desse modo, pode-se fazer um *destructuring assignment* (ou *destructuring bind*) dos seus valores a um conjunto de outras variáveis:

```
x, y = 10, 20   # destructuring assignment: x recebe 10, y recebe 20

for x, y in [(10, 20), (30, 40)]:   # destructuring bind: para cada tupla t da lista
    ...                             #                     x recebe t[0] e y recebe t[1]
```

Por fim, chegamos à sua "estranha" mensagem de erro: *"too many values to unpack"* significa que você tentou fazer um *destructuring bing* onde havia mais valores do lado direito do que do esquerdo:

```
>>> x, y, z = 10, 20
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack

>>> x, y, z = 10, 20, 30   # OK

>>> x, y, z = 10, 20, 30, 40
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

E como isso aconteceu? Simples, no seu `dict` as chaves eram strings, e strings **também aceitam *destructuring bind*!**

```
>>> x, y, z, u, v = "teste"
>>> print(x, y, z)
t e s
>>> print(u, v)
t e
```

Como `Name` possui 4 letras, mas a tupla `(last, first)` só tem 2 elementos, o Python não teve onde colocar as duas últimas letras. Curiosamente, se suas chaves tivessem 2 letras, a mensagem de erro seria diferente:

```
>>> person = {"FN": "Barack", "SN": "Obama"}
>>> for last, first in person:
...     print(person[last, first])
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
KeyError: ('F', 'N')
```

Nesse caso ele estaria atribuindo a `last` o valor `"F"` e a `first` o valor `"N"`. E é claro, como as chaves do dicionários são strings e não tuplas, a chave `("F", "N")` não foi encontrada no dicionário...